# Ask a new question or add it in a comment

Tags: discussion

I was looking for an Excel reader, and found it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/563803/2051332). But now I want to know something about that reader, and found nothing about that in SO nor google.

My question would be really short, so I don't know if make a new question or add a coment in that answer. What should I do?

Comment: Depends. Are you asking for clarification on an answer, or are you asking a new question.

Comment: @KevinB A new question about that specific excel reader, but im pretty sure if I ask my question it would be downvoted couse of its simplicity

Comment: This squeaks by as on-topic because it's _about_ a tool used by programmers instead of _for_ the tool.  Just be sure your questions is specific and ask a new question.

Comment: If it's a new question it should certainly be a new question, asking it as a comment instead is unlikely to yield an answer and won't help any future visitors.